# Lenovo U510, when turn on, power on only 5 seconds, then die

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I have problem with my Lenovo U510. When I press power button, only light on button turn on for 5 seconds (no cooler and display activity) and then goes out (turn off).

Where could be the problem? Is it some diagnostic indication (light turn on for 5 seconds), that for example motherboard is gone? Or processor?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you boot with a bootable USB.  Make the Lenovo Hardware test USB, see if you can boot from that, and run hardware tests.  Otherwise, if the drive is a hard drive, you might see if you can put it in a carrier and recover the contents.

Comment: Do you have a spare power supply?

Comment: @John It is not possible to boot, because laptop turn off after 5 seconds when power on (no display, no cooler, nothing, just light on power button for 5 seconds). I don't have spare power supply, but I suppose if it is power supply problem, laptop wouldn't do anything after power button pressed?

Comment: Time now to get it serviced